# Signal processing: general audio "beat" detection

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

Try to determine the start time and duration of each "beat" in an audio signal (circled in figure below). I guess it is a simple question, and python or Matlab should have toolbox/functions to do this, just couldn't find them. I tried low pass filtering and freq analysis, but neither worked.

[image: sample audio signal]

Answer (score 0):

You could try computing the RMS envelope of your data as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/envelope.html).
You could then detect beats by tracking the amplitude of the envelope: for instance, you could "count" a beat when the envelope amplitude exceeds a user-defined threshold (e.g. 0.005).

I also suggest posting this question on the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).